# Multi-dimensional Vector Pointer

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I have the following multi-dimensional vector

```
int main()
{
    vector< vector<string> > tempVec;

    someFunction(&tempVec);
}

void someFunction(vector< vector<string> > *temp)
{
    //this does not work
    temp[0]->push_back("hello");
}
```

How do i push data into the vector when i have a vector pointer?
The below code does not work.

```
    temp[0]->push_back("hello");
```

Comment: You probably want to take the whole thing by reference and use a dot instead of an arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
(*temp)[0].push_back("hello")
```

That's:

- dereference `temp` to get a `vector<vector<string> > &`
- get first element, a `vector<string> &`
- use `.` instead of `->` because you're no longer handling pointers

That said, it would be easier if `someFunction` took a `vector< vector<string> >&` instead of a pointer: `temp[0].push_back("hello")`. References do not allow pointer arithmetic or null pointers, so they make it harder to screw up and are more suggestive of the actual kind of input required (a single `vector`, not an optional one or an array of them).

Comment: Oh right thats the one! (*temp) been quite awhile since i touched vectors. Thanks! :)